# Nexus Reposiotry manager: 3.0.2 _ does it supports Maven 3, as while creat repository, it shows only Maven 2

Tags: java, maven, nexus

Does Nexus Repository manager works fine with Maven 3 or I have to make some changes to make it work?

See the screen-shot attached.
[image][image]

I have install latest Maven version 3, and Nexus is complaining about Maven plugin version 2.5.

Comment: As i know it works with maven3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's talking about the metadata format, which did not change between Maven 2 and Maven 3. (In fact, it's also shared by Gradle.)

Comment: so, it does support maven 3 ?

Comment: i am getting following errro: [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
clean-plugin:jar:2.5 in http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the updat
e interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: @vicky That's a completely distinct issue and unrelated to this question. It's most likely caused by locking down your repositories (not using Central) and not configuring Nexus to proxy.